# Utilização do componente p:tabView do Primefaces

Tags: primefaces, java-ee, jsf-2.2

Estou utilizando o componente p:tabView do Primefaces:

```
<p:tabView dynamic="true" id="tab_view">
    <c:forEach items="#{tabbedView.listOfTabs}" var="listOfTabs">
     <p:tab title="#{listOfTabs.name}" closable="true">
         <ui:include src="#{listOfTabs.xhtmlIncluded}" />
     </p:tab>
    </c:forEach>
</p:tabView>
```

listOfTabs é um array list de objeto que tem dois campos: name e xhtmlIncluded. O problema é que quando abro duas tab's que utilizam o mesmo xhtml, o JSF aponta duplicidade de nome de componentes, por exemplo:

**javax.servlet.ServletException: A ID de componente tab_view:form já foi encontrada na visualização.**

Tenho que poder abrir duas tabs que carregam o mesmo xhtml.
Utilizo sessionscoped no meu bean.

Alguém já passou por esse problema?

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema adicionando um ui:param ao <ui:include, e esse deve ser único:

<ui:param name="idPrefix" value="#{listOfTabs.id}"/>

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21552654/avoiding-duplicate-ids-when-reusing-facelets-compositions-in-the-same-naming-con